# Как сделать ajax-функцию, возвращающую результат? (Callback)

Tags: callback, ajax, javascript

Нужно сделать проверку "не занят ли email".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию, которая с помощью ajax проверяла, свободен ли адрес, и возвращала бы значение(true/false)

Comment: В смысле „не занят“? Вы имеете ввиду, нет ли уже такого в вашей базе данных?
В любом случае: http://xmlhttprequest.ru/.

Comment: Да, это я и имею ввиду.

Comment: Я знаю, как пользоваться ajax'ом.  
У меня такая же проблема, как описана вот здесь http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-301525.html   
Только здесь всё объяснения заканчивается на словах используйте callback, а как его использовать в этой ситуации, я не понимаю.

Comment: Тут где-то уже было подобное. Решение (если хотите ajax) -- выполнять запрос не асинхронный, а синхронные (правда браузер при этом запросе будет подвисать)

Comment: > Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию, которая с помощью ajax проверяла...
> Я знаю, как пользоваться ajax'ом.

Тогда вообще непонятно о чем вопрос. Приведите код, к-й у Вас есть и укажите в каком конкретно месте и что не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вопрос в том, как послать запрос на проверку серверу и обработать ответ. Пожалуй, правильнее всего было бы найти готовое решение под JQuery или другой фрейворк, наверняка есть модули, но принцип скорее всего там такой же:

```
<script>
    function ajax(query, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/' + query);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) callback(xhr.responceText);
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }

    function check() {
        var email = document.querySelector('input#email').value;
        ajax('?emailToCheck=' + email, function(response) {
            if (response == 'correct') alert('Email is correct');
            else alert('Email is busy');
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="email" onblur="check()">
```

При потере полем ввода фокуса выполняется функция check, которая выполняет функцию ajax со строкой запроса и колбэком в качестве параметров. Когда приходит ответ, колбэк выполняется с текстом ответа в качестве параметра, тут просто делает alert, а можно например изменить цвет текста в инпуте на красный или крестик рядом нарисовать.

Comment: Не понимаю в данном примере преимущества GET перед POST. Объясните?

Comment: А где вы увидели что написано о преимуществе, просто пример

Answer (score 0):

уперлись вы в этот `callback`, да не надо так париться, вообще `callback` нужно использовать в отдельно взятых случаях, а проверку `email` делать через `php+mysql`, если есть такой ящик, возвращаем `1`, если нету `0`, в `ajax` достаточно использовать `success` под это дело, вы главное разберитесь с `ajax`-запросами.